# Что за формат строки?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, что за формат и каким образом можно спарсить?

> a["{"args":["9in","{\"c\": \"rgb(0,0,255)\",
> \"X-Successful\": true, \"f\": \"default\", \"i\":
> \"HPTZ5R56F093AC\", \"m\": \"il\",
> \"tipped_alot_recently\": false, \"is_mod\": false,
> \"tid\": 14255784, \"tipped_tons_recently\": false,
> \"tipped_recently\":
> true}"],"callback":null,"method":"onMsg"}"]

Похоже на JSON, но `JSON.parse` даёт ошибку, указывая на первый символ.

Comment: откуда вы это получаете?

Comment: Возможно это не json, а javascript. Если вытащить строку из квадратных скобок, то она теоретически должна распарситься.

Comment: И еще проверьте, у вас эта строка выглядит как в при просмотре вопроса, или как при редактировании? Строка из квадратных скобок, которая видна при просмотре вопроса - не декодируется, а если открыть редактирование вопроса, скопировать строку из квадратных скобок, убрать лишние переносы строк и знаки цитирования, Python успешно парсит как JSON: https://ideone.com/J3WC8Z

Comment: Тут активно используются двойные кавычки внутри двойных кавычек. Это нехорошо. Если начало строки `a["` и конец строки `"]` заменить на одинарные кавычки `'`, а также убрать двойные кавычки вокруг объекта `"{\"c\": \"rgb(0,0, ..... : true}"`, то строка [парсится](https://clck.ru/TZq7v).

Comment: _"откуда вы это получаете?"_ - Это строка, содержащаяся в поле `data` объекта, который передаётся в обработчик `WebSocket.onmessage`.

Comment: _"Возможно это не json, а javascript. Если вытащить строку из квадратных скобок, то она теоретически должна распарситься. "_ - Каким образом это сделать? Мы имеем объект типа `string`, содержащий представленную последовательность символов.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже это что-то сломанное. Потому, что без `a["` и `"]` внутренняя часть это "кусок" JavaScript-a:

```js
var x = {"args":["9in","{\"c\": \"rgb(0,0,255)\",\"X-Successful\": true, \"f\": \"default\", \"i\": \"HPTZ5R56F093AC\", \"m\": \"il\", \"tipped_alot_recently\": false, \"is_mod\": false, \"tid\": 14255784, \"tipped_tons_recently\": false, \"tipped_recently\": true}"],"callback":null,"method":"onMsg"};

console.log(x);
```

А внутри массива строка JavaScript-a, которая представляет собой валидный JSON. (Это не JSON, а именно строка JavaScript-a с экранированными кавычками).

```js
var json = "{\"c\": \"rgb(0,0,255)\",\"X-Successful\": true, \"f\": \"default\", \"i\": \"HPTZ5R56F093AC\", \"m\": \"il\", \"tipped_alot_recently\": false, \"is_mod\": false, \"tid\": 14255784, \"tipped_tons_recently\": false, \"tipped_recently\": true}";

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

Comment: Ну а как убрать кавычки и получить объект? Изначально имеем `string`

Comment: "Распечатать" эту строку из бек-энда в тег `<script> сюда </script>`. Или во фронт-энде создать тег `<script></script>` с контентом из этой строки, а затем прицепить этот скрипт к DOM.

Comment: Нет ли иного варианта? Подобных сообщений будет очень много каждую секунду.

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос - как наиболее эфективно эвалуировать (eval) подобные строки. Не забудьте привести пример строки.